# From a paragraph get only first two lines in tcl/tk

Tags: string, tcl, tk-toolkit, trim

For reference this is how the paragraph looks like.

```
{180319 arun S B} first set of chars. first chars.
{180316 yyay S B} second set of chars. second line.
{180314 ramaw S B} third line. third line. third line.
{180309 jfds S B} fouth line
{180221 shrbsd S B} fifth line.fith line part 2.
{180214 shrbs S B} sixth line.
```

In this I need to extract first two lines. like

```
{180319 arun S B} first set of chars. first chars.
{180316 yyay S B} second set of chars. second line.
```

I don't have any idea how to do this in tcl. can you please suggest me to do this. I have surfed many hours in online though I'm new to tcl so it is hard to understand me. Thanks

Comment: Is how I have reformatted the text correct for what you're starting out from? Also, is the data in a string or in a file?

Comment: You might want to start with the [Tcl tutorial](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this:

1. split the paragraph into lines and join the first 2 lines:

   ```
   set lines [split $para \n]
   set first2 [lrange $lines 0 1]
   set wanted [join $first2 \n]
   # or
   set wanted [join [lrange [split $para \n] 0 1] \n]
   ```
2. find the position of the 2nd newline and take the characters from the start of the paragraph up to that position

   ```
   set firstnewline [string first \n $para]
   set secondnewline [string first \n $para $firstnewline+1]
   set wanted [string range $para 0 $secondnewline-1]
   ```

   You can also get the 2nd newline index with

   ```
   set secondnewline [lindex [regexp -all -inline -indices \n $para] 1 0]
   ```

Tcl commands are documented here: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm

Answer (score 0):

working TCL code will is follow :

```html
   set file [open c:/filename.txt ]
     set file_device [read  $file]
     set data [split $file_device "\n"]

        for {set count 0} {$count < 2} {incr count} {
        
        puts $data
        
        # for every iterartion one line will be printed.
     # split /n is use for getting the end of each line.
        # open command open the file at given path. 
        # read command is use to read the open file.
     }
     close $file
     break
```

This will work for sure.

Comment: If we define "work" as "print the entire contents of the file as a list of lines twice", then yes.

Comment: Not slicing...@M.D.P